# Umbraco Back Office Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, umbraco

Has anyone had any experience trying to write a custom Membership Provider for the Umbraco back office? I've run into all sorts of trouble trying to make this happen. You can see some more details here:

[Umbraco Issue Tracker](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=25232)

If you made it work, what steps did you take and how did you make it get along with the *umbracoUsers* table in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer to this is that it doesn't really seem possible right now to write your own back office membership provider. There are just too many problems standing in the way. I've posted this as a bug to the Umbraco team.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better ask these type of questions on the umbraco forum, but I've managed to do this. The Membershipsection has an attribute default provider, change that to the provider you use and it should work.

Cheers,

Richard

Comment: Hi Richard. I did ask this question in the forum, including keeping it updated with my research. Unfortunately no one has responded, so I've tried looking for help in multiple places. The trouble is that it doesn't just work when you switch out the back office provider, unless you are using the standard AD provider that ships with .NET. You can see the details of this in the bug report I linked to on the Umbraco CodePlex site.